# gdebi install now failing on Trusty

Tags: 14.04, package-management, aptitude, gdebi

Anyone know what's happened to gdebi?  Up until the end of September our scripts were working fine - though a little long winded.

```
  sudo apt-get install -y aptitude 
  sudo aptitude install -y gdebi
  wget http://www.princexml.com/download/prince_10r7-1_ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb
  sudo gdebi --non-interactive prince_10r7-1_ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb
```

Since October, the last command now fails because gdebi is not fully installing.  Upon inspecting the console logs we see this key difference in the aptitude install of gdebi since October:

```
  Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main gdebi-core all 0.9.5.3ubuntu2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
```

It seems that the `gdebi-core` has fallen out of the `trusty-updates` repository!

My questions are:

i) Does anyone know who I speak to to get it re-instated?, or

ii) Does anyone know a better way to do an unattended install of a deb package not in the Ubuntu repositories, than going through the aptitude/gdebi route above (for info, we are stuck on Ubuntu 14.04)?

Comment: Ooops, turns out all that is needed is an **apt-get update** - that's embarrassing, sorry!